# Program that computes the nth element of a number series given by a formula

Tags: c

> Write a method/function with name cpSeries that computes the nth element in a series of numbers,  given by the formula: a(n) = (a(n-1))2+a(n-2) when: n>1 and assuming that: a(1)=1, a(0)=0 Note that indexing of the series starts from 0.

I have already written the above code but it runs for an infinite time and I don't know how to fix it in order to compute the nth element.

Any ideas? I have to use only functions to solve this problem.

```
# include <stdio.h>

int cpSeries(int n)
{    
    int Nthterm = 0;
    int i;
    
    if (n==0) {
        cpSeries(0) == 0;
    }
    else if (n==1) {
        cpSeries(1) == 1;
    }
    for (i=0; i<=n; i++){
        Nthterm = cpSeries((n-1))*cpSeries((n-1)) + cpSeries((n-2));
        return Nthterm;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n=6;
    printf("The Nth term of the series is: %d",cpSeries(n));
}
```

Comment: Did you mean `return 0;` when you wrote `cpSeries(0) == 0;`?

Comment: Yes. I thought it was  the same thing.

Comment: BTW, the 8th element of that series is outside the range of a 32-bit integer, while the 9th element is enough to overflow a 64-bit integer.

Comment: That function's body could consist of a one-liner `return` statement only: `return n<2 ? n : cpSeries(n-1)*cpSeries(n-1) + cpSeries(n-2);`. A recursive solution to this problem is a very bad example of recursion (a valid one but tremendously inefficient). An iterative solution would be much efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the provided equation gives you the nth element, I don't see the need for a loop.

Also, in the if conditions, you are calling the function again, but what you should do is return the value you need.

```
int cpSeries(int n){
    
    int Nthterm;
    
    if (n==0){
        
        Nthterm = 0;
    }
    else if (n==1){
        
        Nthterm = 1;
    }
    else {

        Nthterm = cpSeries((n-1))*cpSeries((n-1)) + cpSeries((n-2));   
    }

    return Nthterm;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your final conditions just call the function another time instead of returning 0 or 1.

instead of

```
if (n==0) {
    cpSeries(0) == 0;
}
else if (n==1) {
    cpSeries(1) == 1;
}
```

use

```
if (n==0) {
    return 0;
}
else if (n==1) {
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C is not a declarative language where you can specify the return value `y` of a function `f` given an argument `x` by writing something like `f(x) = y`, but you have to use a return statement.

Change `cpSeries(0) == 0;` to

```
return 0;
```

to avoid the infinite recursion (and the same for `n == 1`).